# JavaScript: figuring out max memory that could be used in a program

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, memory, v8

JavaScript in Chrome (or any other browser for that matter, but I rather limit the discussion to Chrome to make it simpler) does not provide an API which can be used to observe memory related information (e.g. how much memory is being used by the current tab where the JS is running).

I am looking for a creative solution for getting an estimation of how much bytes I can cache in a JavaScript object that my web page is running. The problem definition is that I would like to cache as much as possible.

Can anyone think of a decent way of estimating how much memory can a tab handle before it will crash / become unusable on a machine? I guess a statistical approach could work out fine for some cases, but I'm looking for something more dynamic.

Comment: are you looking for profiling?

Comment: What about simply trying it? Pushing to the limits (on your machine) and extrapolating? We should be talking many, many megabytes here, but it depends on what you mean by "cache."

Comment: that really need a creative solution :) but the ressource problem you described isn't just releated to the memory you need CPU performance as well. i would try to out if you can calculate an index for the clients performance as diEcho suggested. For example a worker with a heavy string operation and based on this results build your app

Comment: @diEcho - ideally I would do real time memory monitoring to figure out when the client cannot handle storing more data in the memory, but since it is not possible in browser JS (no browser API's for that), I am looking to perform some kind of an estimation.

Comment: In Chrome Shift+Esc brings up the Chrome task manager. This shows the amount of memory consumed by each tab and plugin running. Might be helpful

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - This is kind of what I mean by "statistical approach". I can figure out what the average client can handle and use that, but I am wondering if there's some better way.

Comment: @JanWiemers - true, but in my case the only metric that matters is memory (I am talking about simply storing data inside an object called _cache).

Comment: @jasonscript - thanks. I know how to profile memory using Chrome dev tools, the problem is that I'd like to achieve a similar benchmark using JavaScript on the client side, so that I could decide adaptively how much data (in-memory object) can a client machine handle at a given time.